# How to prevent a callback from firing that is fed into a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I have two functions.

```
function function_a(callback) {
   if (some_condition===true) {
   callback // fire the callback
   }
}

function function_b() {
    ... do some action
}
```

My script calls:

```
function_a(function_b());
```

Meaning, the `callback` in `function_a()` will be the execution of `function_b()`.

However I do not always want `function_b()` to fire. I only want it to fire when `some_condition===true` (as in the `function_a()` body).

The problem right now is that whenever I feed a callback function into the parameters of another function it fires it automatically without running through the script of the function to determine whether or not the callback needs to fire at all.

Is there something I am doing wrong or some different way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: In JavaScript, arguments are always evaluated first. `foo(bar())` executes `bar` and passes its *return value* to `foo`. Unless `function_b` returns a function, your code is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `function_a(function_b);`.

Right now you are not passing `function_b` itself, you are calling it immediately and passing in its return value.

Your `function_a` should do `callback()` rather than `callback`.

Answer (score 3):

Parentheses cause a function to "execute" or "fire". So like Comptonburger said, drop the parentheses for the "script call", but add the parentheses on the callback.

```
function function_a(callback) {
    if (some_condition === true) {
        callback(); // parentheses do the "firing"
    }
}

function function_b() {
    // ... do some action
}

// Script calls:
// No parentheses on function_b because we 
// don't want to "fire it" right here and now.
function_a( function_b );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass `function_b()` as a string and evaluate it after condition passes.

```
function function_a(callback) {
   if (some_condition===true) {
       eval(callback); // fire the callback
   }
}

function function_b() {
    ... do some action
}

function_a("function_b()");
```